# Why does assigning [dateClass] in mat-calendar have no effect?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

I would like to add some custom stylings for certain days shown in the mat-calendar component from angular material. After a little bit of research I came across the dateClass property which seems to be suited for this task. Though no matter what I tried, the calendar always looks the same.

My current setup looks like following:

calendar.component.ts:

```
dateClass = (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => { return 'my-date'; }
```

calendar.component.html:

```
<mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass"></mat-calendar>
```

calendar.component.css:

```
.my-date { background-color: red; }
```

Assigning [dateClass] seems to have no effect at all. I would expect all days to have a red background but the calendar always looks the same:
[Angular Material Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX02i.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

OP pointed out `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` is also needed, as it was included in the stackblitz demo.

Original:

Your css is too broad, thus it's not getting applied to anything. To apply the css to date buttons, try this:

```
button.my-date {
  background: red;
}
```

[Stackblizt demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-61lpia?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.css,src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.ts)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Stackblitz example! Turned out I was missing ViewEncapsulation.None. I'll make sure to make use of this service in the future to give better details on my questions. Btw. a broad class definition like '.my-date' seems to be no issue on my side, works as intended now.

Comment: Btw, I noticed I my stack demo, the css doesn't work, if I remove the `button` from `button.my-date`

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I had marked my rules with `!important`, which also works but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I would add a note on using `ViewEncapsulation.None`:
Please be aware of the fact that adding that particular `ViewEncapsulation` will leak the css classes into other components when you navigate away from the component that has the `ViewEncapsulation.None` applied to.
It's very annoying when you follow the Angular Material documentation, only to find out that you still need to work a lot more to achieve quite a simple UI change.